# How to check if switch subject is object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Ajax response could be a `json object`, `bool` or various `string values`

Can I check if it was an object in  a switch statement?

```
$.post('url',{some:'data'},function(response){
   switch (response){
   case true:
     console.log('is true');
     break;
   case false:
     console.log('is false');
     break;
   case 'success':
     console.log('is success');
     break;
   case typeof this === 'object' // thought I'd try this but it didn't work.
     console.log('is object');
     break;
   }
});
```

Comment: When you say your AJAX response can be a `bool`, what does that look like on the wire? Are you sure it's not still JSON? In that case, since jQuery automatically deserialises JSON, your question is really "how do I find the type of a variable `var`", which has been asked many times before.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, in that respect the bool is in fact json but the switch detects them. what I need is a case that detects `{foo:'bar',this:'that'}`

Comment: Your API sounds wonky. It should be far more consistent than this. Have a constant schema and changing data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`switch` performs an equality comparison between the argument and the `case` expressions. So `case typeof this === 'object'` calculates the value of `typeof this === 'object'`, which will be either `true` or `false` depending on what `this` is (it will be `window` in your callback), and compares that to `response`. It won't test the type of `response`. If you want to perform a switch on the type of `response`, use that as the argument.

Try:

```
switch (typeof response) {
case 'boolean':
    if (response) {
        console.log('is true');
    } else {
        console.log('is false');
    }
    break;
case 'string':
    if (response == 'success') {
        console.log('is success');
    } else {
        // do something
    }
    break;
case 'object':
    console.log('is object');
    break;
}
```

More generally, `switch` should be used when you want to do a series of equality tests on the same value. You can't mix equality and type tests in the same `switch`; you need to use `switch` for one, `if` for the other.

Answer (score 0):

Have a default case :

```
default : 
     if(typeof response === 'object'){ // thought I'd try this but it didn't work.
     console.log('is object');
     }
     break;
```